# Building telegram azure bot to deliver dynamic questionaaires, along with location sharing

Tags: c#, python, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am developing a location-based recommender system, which uses a chatbot which:

**Situation**

1. Gets the users current location via a channel such as telegram/facebook messenger or other
2. Uses the chatbot, which shares this location with a backend azure serverless function, and which sends a set of personalization multiple-choice questions with options to the chatbot.
3. The chatbot asks those questions( according to the questions sent from the backend), to the users, and sends the user's selected answers back to the backend. Note: the questions and their choices, are entirely dynamic, and a static questionnaire cannot be assumed.
4. The backend personalizes the recommendation for the landmarks around the user, according to the answers, and displays the recommendation to the user.

**Questions**:

1. I read lots of tutorials on doing this with microsoft botbuilder( which is a requirment) but dynamic form-dialogs dont seem to be possible ( I only saw statically coded form). The questions and their options should be retrieved via a back-end REST API call and the json will be parsed to make the Q and A dialog. With the option for each question being sent back to the server to store. how do I make this happen?
2. Since its a user-location-dependent service, how do I take the current location of the user, from the deployed channel(i.e. telegram),into the chatbot ( and then send it to server backend). is there any way to do this using the microsoft botbuilder framework?

Since I am very new to azure and botbuilder framework, thanks in advance for any help!

Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The text for a message can be retrieved from anywhere.  This example pulls messages from a mocked up service, and walks the user through the steps one at a time: https://github.com/EricDahlvang/MultiTurnHelpStepsBot

2) This library might help: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location